# How to programmatically retrieve the GID of a running process

Tags: linux, c, proc

I need to write some C code to check the effective GID of a running process whose PID I know. I've not found any direct way to do this. There are a number of heavyweight kludges I could use, such as invoking `popen("/bin/ps ARGS", "r")` and parsing its output, or `fopen("/proc/PID/status", "r")` and parsing *that* output, but I'm looking for a cleaner, more direct approach. If only `getegid()` took a PID argument...

Comment: Isn't this what you want? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpgid.html

Comment: @slm No, `getpgid` concerns the PGID = process group ID, which is a parameter related to job control and not related to the security credentials UID/EUID/GID/EGID

Comment: OK - sorry to keep throwing links to you but what about this code: http://c.happycodings.com/c-on-unix/code12.html

Comment: @slm The OP already mentioned `getegid()` and that system call is only able to give you your *own* GID, not that of another process. Too bad about that :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a very popular question, so I want to make the answer very clear. @MarkPlotnick gave the best answer, as a comment to the previous (pretty good) answer, but we haven't gotten his attention to repost it so I can accept it as a proper answer and help people out. So, with apologies to Mark:

> Mark Plotnick says: You can also do stat("/proc/nnn", &stb); the process's effective gid will be in stb.st_gid. This is simultaneously more portable (it works on Linux and FreeBSD) and less portable (it's not documented).

Thanks Mark!

Comment: `stat` is good. Still doesn't give additional groups. Or I can't see that.

Comment: There are two separate issues here. A process has only one GID. Perhaps you are thinking of how a user can type "groups" and see multiple group memberships. That mechanism is unrelated.

Comment: I was looking for a way to see all group permissions a process has, when I found this question. So it depends on lurker's needs whether it is related or not ;)
btw I have upvoted your answer which is good. I am merely pointing out a limitation of this method.

Comment: @akostadinov It is a common confusion that people expect a process can belong to multiple groups. It can't. A process belongs to a single group. Users can belong to multiple groups, and files can have permissions for multiple groups, but processes can't.

Comment: Here's a reasonable description of how groups work:
https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/11/20/groups/

Ignore the first section. For some reason the blogger decided to start describing groups incorrectly and then correct it. Not helpful.

Comment: Your last comment (very useful) contradicts your previous one. In the blog is described that supplementary groups are also attributed to the process. Otherwise there would be no way to access files based on supplementary group permissions from my shell.

Comment: A process can only have a single GID and a single effective GID (which was what the OP asked about). Those are very specific concepts and data structures in Unix/Linux. But you can have supplementary groups, which provide the behavior you observe.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any portable way to do this. I thought maybe `ptrace()`, but I can't see how from the manpage. Even if that works, "tracing" the other process in any way is probably unnecessarily invasive

For Linux, your suggestion to use `fopen("/proc/PID/status", "r")` is about as clean and direct as you're going to get. It seems to be what [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) does.

Comment: It seems crazy to parse multiple lines of a text file to do a simple thing like this, but this is what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: You can also do `stat("/proc/nnn", &stb)`; the process's effective gid will be in `stb.st_gid`. This is simultaneously more portable (it works on Linux and FreeBSD) and less portable (it's not documented).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick great idea, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That *is* a great idea! Somehow I never saw it when you made this comment. Can you make it an actual answer so I can mark it as such for others?