# How could one determine UID/GID of running process

Tags: permissions, top, unix-philosophy, uid

Is there any way to retrieve UID/GID of running process?
Currently, I know only way of looking it up in htop. But I don't want to depend on third-party tool, prefer to use builtin unix commands. 
Could you suggest a few useful oneliners?

This didn't satisfy my curiousity:

**[How to programmatically retrieve the GID of a running process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140451/how-to-programmatically-retrieve-the-gid-of-a-running-process)**

top shows only user but not the group.

Comment: Why didn't the linked question satisfy your curiosity? On Linux, `/proc/PID/status` gives you the real, effective, saved set and file system uid and gid...

Comment: But what about other OSes? Solaris?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$ stat -c "%u %g" /proc/$pid/
1000 1000
```

or

```
$ egrep "^(U|G)id" /proc/$pid/status
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

or with only bash builtins:

```
$ while read -r line;do [ "${line:1:2}" = "id" ] && echo $line;done < /proc/17359/status 
Pid: 17359
Uid: 1000 1000 1000 1000
Gid: 1000 1000 1000 1000
```

Comment: 1. Why [GU]id have four values in a row?
2. I use GNU/Linux. however, what commands to use on other fairly POSIX-compliant unix oses?

Comment: Per the man page - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html - the 4 values represent ".....Real, effective, saved set, and filesystem..."

Answer (score 5):

Or assuming a *BSD system (for `ps` is unportable, and OpenBSD ditched `/proc` a bunch of releases ago now)

```
ps -o uid,gid -p ...
```

Comment: 1. Could you give some insight white OpenBSD project did that? Interesting, accounting its security goals.

Comment: 2. Could you combine with above answers for GNU/Linux systems. So I could give my vote for complete answer.

Comment: @Bulat M.   See [this thread](https://marc.info/?t=125341144400003&r=1&w=2) on the openbsd-misc mailing list from 2009. The `procfs` filesystem was finally completely removed in [release 5.7](https://www.openbsd.org/57.html) (May 2015).

Comment: @BulatM. This answer works on many Unix variants. If you use `-o user,group` instead of `-o uid,gid`, it works on all POSIX systems but displays names instead of numeric values.

Comment: `ps` has `OUTPUT MODIFIER`, to see numeric UID, just pass `n` to `ps`, e.g. `ps n -ef`